# Java - Pasar un array como parámetro en un método de clase

Tags: java, array, clase, método, parámetros

¿Cómo puedo pasar un array (ya está rellenado) como parametro por un método de clase?

Este es mi código:

```
      // Creamos un array con 10 números enteros
      array = new int[10];

      // Rellenamos el array
      for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        array[i] = sc.nextInt();

      }

      media.calcularMediaArray( **Pasar array** );
```

Un saludo.

Comment: `media.calcularMediaArray( array );` así lo pasas, tal vez quieras saber como lo recibes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sencillamente pasa el array con su nombre y recíbelo con su tipo correcto en la otra función.

```
calcularMediaArray(array);

public static double calcularMediaArray(int[] a)
{
    double total = 0.0;

    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        total += a[i];
    }

  return total/a.length;
}
```

Recuerda que el array se declara tal que

```
int[] array = new int[10];
```

Por tanto es simplemente detallar su tipo en la función en la que lo quieres usar como argumento.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasarle el Array solo con el nombre del Array:
`media.calcularMediaArray(array)`, siempre que en la función de tu clase hayas declarado que el parámetro que recibirás será un Array de int:

```
public int calcularMediaArray (int[] miarray){ //tu código }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Creamos un array con 10 números enteros
  int[] array = new int[10];

  // Rellenamos el array
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    array[i] = sc.nextInt();

  }

  media.calcularMediaArray(array);
```

Corregi la inicialización del array porque te iba a salir error. Solo tienes que pones el nombre con el cual lo declaraste.